# Weird nav buttons on mobile CSS

Tags: html, css, mobile

So I'm doing a project for school and I can't seem to get the mobile part of this page to work right. When I shrink the browser window, the nav buttons turn into little squares for some reason. I've fallen behind a bit and I'm just stuck on this, starting to drive me crazy. Any help would be amazing!

-Thefinder

[Here's the screwed up page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K58C.png)

[Here's what it's supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvFRI.png)

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
body { margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       background-color: #FFFFCC;
       background-image: none; 
      }
#wrapper { width: 100%;
           min-width: 0;
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
           box-shadow: none;
           border-radius: 0;
           border-style: none;
           }
header { background-image: url(primemobile.gif);
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000033;
         height: 100%;
         }
h1 { margin: 0;
     text-indent: 0;
     font-size: 3.7em;
     padding-left: 2em;
     white-space: normal;
     }
nav { float: none;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: 0.5em;
      }
nav a { padding: 0.2em;
        margin-left: 0.3em;
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        }
main { padding: 2.5em 1em 2.5em 1em;
       margin: 0;
       font-size: 90%;
       clear: both; 
       }

}
@media only all and (max-width: 768px) {
h1 { font-size: 2.4em;
     padding-top: 0.25em;
     padding-left: 1.5em;
     }
nav { width: 98%;
    }
nav a { padding: 0.5em;
        width: 40%;
        float: left;
        min-width: 5em;
        margin-left: 0.5em;
        }
main { padding: 0.6em;
     }
.floatleft { float: none;
             padding-right: 0;
             padding-bottom: 0;
             }
h3 { padding-top: 0;
     margin: 0;
     }
dd { line-height: 100%;
    }
footer { padding: 0.5em;
         margin: 0;
         }  
#mobile { display: inline; 
        }
#desktop { display: none;
}

}
body { background-color: #000033;
       color: #003300;
       font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       background-image: url(primediagonal.png);
       }
header { color: #48751A;
        background-image: url(primelogo.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100px;
        }
h1 { text-indent: 100%;
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     }
h2 { color: #003366;
    }
h3 { color: #006600;
     padding-top: 10px;
    }
nav { float: left;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      width: 150px;
     }
dd { font-style: italic;
     font-size: .90em;
     line-height: 200%;
    }
.contact { font-weight: bold;
           font-size: .90em;
           font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
          } 
footer { font-style: italic;
         font-size: .60em;
         clear: both;
         margin-left: 180px;
        }
#wrapper { width: 80%;
           margin-right: auto;
           margin-left: auto;
           background-color: #ffffcc;
           min-width: 700px;
           max-width: 960px;
           padding-top: 0;
           padding-right: 0;
           padding-bottom: 20px;
           padding-left: 30px;
           border: 1px ridge #00332B;
           border-radius: 15px;
           box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 3px 3px #00332B;
          } 
img { border: none;
    }
nav a { text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFFFCC;
        font-weight: bold;
        border: 3px outset #CCCCCC;
        padding: 5px;
        }
nav a:link { background-color: #003366;
}
nav a:visited { background-color: #48751A;
}
nav a:hover { border: 3px inset #333333;
}
nav ul { list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding-left: 0; 
}
main { margin-left: 180px;
       padding-right: 20px;
       padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.floatleft { float: left;
             padding-right: 20px;
             padding-bottom: 20px; 
}
.clear { clear: left; 
}
#mobile { display: none; 
}
#desktop { display: inline;
}
header, nav, main, footer { display: block; }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="prime.css">
    <!--[if lt IE9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
    <title>Prime Properties</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
    <h1><img src="primelogo.gif" alt="Prime's Company Logo" height="100px" width="600px"></h1>
</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href="listings.html">Listings</a></li> 
        <li><a href="financing.html">Financing</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<main>
    <p>Prime Properties is prepared to market and sell your property.</p>
    <p>The philosophy of Prime Properties is to promote our clients, not ourselves.</p>
    <p>We can also help you find the property that meets your needs:</p>

    <ul>
        <li>location</li>
        <li>price</li>
        <li>features</li>
    </ul>
<div class="contact">
    <p>Prime Properties<br>
    3055 Bode Road<br>
    Schaumburg, IL 60194<br>
    </p>

    <p><a id="mobile" href="tel:847-555-5555">847-555-5555</a><span id="desktop">847-555-5555</span></p>
</div>
    <br>
    </main>

<footer>

    <br>
    Copyright &copy; 2014 Prime Properties<br>

</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
body { margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       background-color: #FFFFCC;
       background-image: none; 
      }
#wrapper { width: 100%;
           min-width: 0;
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
           box-shadow: none;
           border-radius: 0;
           border-style: none;
           }
header { background-image: url(primemobile.gif);
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000033;
         height: 100%;
         }
h1 { margin: 0;
     text-indent: 0;
     font-size: 3.7em;
     padding-left: 2em;
     white-space: normal;
     }
nav { float: none;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: 0.5em;
      }
nav a { padding: 0.2em;
        margin-left: 0.3em;
        float: left;
        }
main { padding: 2.5em 1em 2.5em 1em;
       margin: 0;
       font-size: 90%;
       clear: both; 
       }

}
@media only all and (max-width: 768px) {
h1 { font-size: 2.4em;
     padding-top: 0.25em;
     padding-left: 1.5em;
     }
nav { width: 98%;
    }
nav a { padding: 0.5em;
        width: 40%;
        float: left;
        min-width: 5em;
        margin-left: 0.5em;
        }
main { padding: 0.6em;
     }
.floatleft { float: none;
             padding-right: 0;
             padding-bottom: 0;
             }
h3 { padding-top: 0;
     margin: 0;
     }
dd { line-height: 100%;
    }
footer { padding: 0.5em;
         margin: 0;
         }  
#mobile { display: inline; 
        }
#desktop { display: none;
}

}
body { background-color: #000033;
       color: #003300;
       font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       background-image: url(primediagonal.png);
       }
header { color: #48751A;
        background-image: url(primelogo.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100px;
        }
h1 { text-indent: 100%;
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     }
h2 { color: #003366;
    }
h3 { color: #006600;
     padding-top: 10px;
    }
nav { float: left;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.2em;
     }
     nav ul li{
        display:inline-block;
     }
dd { font-style: italic;
     font-size: .90em;
     line-height: 200%;
    }
.contact { font-weight: bold;
           font-size: .90em;
           font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
          } 
footer { font-style: italic;
         font-size: .60em;
         clear: both;
         margin-left: 180px;
        }
#wrapper { width: 80%;
           margin-right: auto;
           margin-left: auto;
           background-color: #ffffcc;
           min-width: 700px;
           max-width: 960px;
           padding-top: 0;
           padding-right: 0;
           padding-bottom: 20px;
           padding-left: 30px;
           border: 1px ridge #00332B;
           border-radius: 15px;
           box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 3px 3px #00332B;
          } 
img { border: none;
    }
nav a { text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFFFCC;
        font-weight: bold;
        border: 3px outset #CCCCCC;
        padding: 5px;
        }
nav a:link { background-color: #003366;
}
nav a:visited { background-color: #48751A;
}
nav a:hover { border: 3px inset #333333;
}
nav ul { list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding-left: 0; 
}
main { margin-left: 180px;
       padding-right: 20px;
       padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.floatleft { float: left;
             padding-right: 20px;
             padding-bottom: 20px; 
}
.clear { clear: left; 
}
#mobile { display: none; 
}
#desktop { display: inline;
}
header, nav, main, footer { display: block; }
```

Comment: i removed the width attribute in the "nav a" and i added nav ul li { display: inline-block; }

Comment: That made it look better, but I don't understand why my text is sitting way below the nav buttons instead of being in the center of the page with the nav buttons on the left. It's driving me freaking crazy! It looks nothing like it's supposed to.

Comment: Add a <br> after the nav element

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make more media queries to have one for each format. You have to style your nav with some `width` because now the whole nav on every format has a width of `150px;` so it will never be bigger than that. I have made some extra media queries and some small adjustments to the nav in each format so you will have a small start

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
body { margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background-color: #FFFFCC;
   background-image: none; 
  }
#wrapper { width: 100%;
       min-width: 0;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       box-shadow: none;
       border-radius: 0;
       border-style: none;
       }
header { background-image: url(primemobile.gif);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000033;
     height: 100%;
     }
h1 { margin: 0;
 text-indent: 0;
 font-size: 3.7em;
 padding-left: 2em;
 white-space: normal;
 }
nav { float: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  width: 700px;
  }
nav a { padding: 0.2em;
    margin-left: 0.3em;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    }
main { padding: 2.5em 1em 2.5em 1em;
   margin: 0;
   font-size: 90%;
   clear: both; 
   }



}

@media only all and (max-width: 768px) {
h1 { font-size: 2.4em;
 padding-top: 0.25em;
 padding-left: 1.5em;
 }
nav {
    width: 480px;
}
nav a { padding: 0.5em;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    min-width: 5em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    }
main { padding: 0.6em;
 }
.floatleft { float: none;
         padding-right: 0;
         padding-bottom: 0;
         }
h3 { padding-top: 0;
 margin: 0;
 }
dd { line-height: 100%;
}
footer { padding: 0.5em;
     margin: 0;
     }  
#mobile { display: inline; 
    }
#desktop { display: none;
}

}
body { background-color: #000033;
   color: #003300;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   background-image: url(primediagonal.png);
   }
header { color: #48751A;
    background-image: url(primelogo.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
    }
h1 { text-indent: 100%;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 }
h2 { color: #003366;
}
h3 { color: #006600;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
nav { float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;

 }
dd { font-style: italic;
 font-size: .90em;
 line-height: 200%;
}
.contact { font-weight: bold;
       font-size: .90em;
       font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
      } 
footer { font-style: italic;
     font-size: .60em;
     clear: both;
     margin-left: 180px;
    }
#wrapper { width: 80%;
       margin-right: auto;
       margin-left: auto;
       background-color: #ffffcc;
       min-width: 700px;
       max-width: 960px;
       padding-top: 0;
       padding-right: 0;
       padding-bottom: 20px;
       padding-left: 30px;
       border: 1px ridge #00332B;
       border-radius: 15px;
       box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 3px 3px #00332B;
      } 
img { border: none;
}
nav a { text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFCC;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 3px outset #CCCCCC;
    padding: 5px;
    }
nav a:link { background-color: #003366;
}
nav a:visited { background-color: #48751A;
}
nav a:hover { border: 3px inset #333333;
}
nav ul { list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding-left: 0; 
}
main { 
   padding-right: 20px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.floatleft { float: left;
         padding-right: 20px;
         padding-bottom: 20px; 
 }
.clear { clear: left; 
 }
 #mobile { display: none; 
 }
 #desktop { display: inline;
 } 
 header, nav, main, footer { display: block; }


@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
main {
margin-left: 180px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 410px) {
nav {
width: 260px;
}
}
```